# Solving Non-linear equation for Computational math

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

Question is, the curve $y = x^3 - 2x^2 + x -1$ intersects the parabola $y = 2x^2 + 3x + 1$. Locate the intersection then use both False Position Method and Secant Method. (Numerically)
I really need help on this question. I don't really know what to start and what to do. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

To find the intersection of these curves we can write $$x^3 - 2x^2 + x - 1 = 2x^2 +3x + 1.$$
How should we rewrite this equation so that we can use those methods?

Comment: So, after we put two formula together, we use the false position method and secant method. $x^3-4x^2-2x-2 = 0$

Comment: @HyoDong Kim You've rearranged slightly incorrectly there. But yes, that is what you do after you set $f(x) = \text{LHS}$.

Comment: Thank you so much..... I was so confused when the question gave me the two equations and the intersection.

Comment: @HyoDong Kim You're welcome! Once you've seen this kind of thing once, it should no longer confuse you when you see it again.

Comment: One last question, How do I find the two initial points for the secant method?

Comment: @HyoDong Kim As with most of these things, you try and make an initial guess and hope that it converges to your solution (yes, there are cases where after iteration you end up just diverging from any actual solutions).